# I need to countif-match(two side-by-side cells) anywhere in the sheet

Tags: google-sheets

Anywhere in the sheet there could be 'Apple' in one cell (say A1) and 'Available' in beside cell (say (B1)

How to get the count?

[SAMPLE SHEET](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IdzBVLTplyEzR108Q1kBUl2L-nj7yJvpjZ7DspTEYms/edit#gid=1450082558)

Comment: While several functions are similar between Excel and Google Sheets, many other there aren't, so it's better use one tag or the other unless the question it's about interoperability/compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your test spreadsheet try:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:K,"Apple",B:L,"Available")
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe u should format your data like this:

[image: EXAMPLE IS HERE]

Then if u want to count how much Apple is available then just use this formula:
=COUNTIFS(A:A;"Apple";B:B;"Available")

Comment: Someone from google product forms gave it : =countifs(A:J,"Apple",B:K,"Available")